# BULK INSERT command is silently exiting without any error/exception after processing 315 batches in MSSQL

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert, pyodbc

I storing quite huge dataset(Billions of rows) into `MSSQL Server 2008 R2` table. Using `BCP` command to push data to table.
But BCP is just silently exiting after processing `315 batches`, I tested with `different batch size (1 record per batch, 100 record per batch, 1000 record per batch, 1000000 record per batch)`.
But it does not depends on batch size, just exiting after processing `315 batches`.

Executing `BCP` commands using `python pyodbc`.

I do not have any clue why this is happening. What approach I should take to sort this out ? Support on this will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you include the full BCP command in your question please?

Comment: `BULK INSERT SampleTable FROM '\\location\\to\\file.txt'
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR='|',
  ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'',
  ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000, 
  FIRSTROW=1,
);
`

This is the exact sample query which is being executed.

Comment: It would help if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49882197/edit) your question, and include the exact statement in the question itself. Not just for readers to get a clear view of your problem, it also bumps your question. Also, BULK INSERT and BCP are two different "beasts". They both do bulky things, but one is a T-SQL command, the other is a command line utility that is bundled with SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, will edit

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The issue is related to the database cursor object.
- The root cause behind this is database cursor object is getting full and I had to do pagination like traversal to the cursor object.
- Because cursor was I was not able to capture the latest output of my stored procedure. In my case my cursor is getting full after 315 (return statements from stored procedure. Example output of insert statement like `10 rows inserted`).

**Sample python code**

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(username, password)

query = "a stored procedure"

# Execute query and get cursor object
cursor = conn.execute(query)

# Clearing cursor
while cursor.nextset():
    result  = cursor.fetchall() if cursor.description else None
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!